# Can I Make a Website Tracker With Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Nodejs. I want to make an server which listen an website and when new post is sharing, the server will send me a notification.

***Edited:*** I learned some node Library and now I created my own twitter bot with Nodecron, Axios, JsDom and Cheerio. I'm getting activity of a person on twitter. Whem person who I follow tweet or like others tweet telebot send me a message. Thank you for your answers and negative points :)

Comment: Yes. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You of course can do that. I think you want to know a few keywords to start searching for how to solve you problem.
As far as I understand you need to implement a service that watches for new posts on a webpage and should send a notification to you if there are new ones.

First of all you need to use something like the `axios` npm package (I would recommend this one) to make HTTP requests. You then need to constantly make requests to the webpage and see if any changes occurred. For this you either need an endless loop, which I would not recommend or a scheduler like `nodecron` - which I would recommend.

You could then send a request to the webpage every minute (or whatever) and check if any changes occurred. Then you could send an email to you email address for the notification. For this I would recommend the `nodemailer` package.
I cannot give any further instructions on how to check for differences in the responses of the request to the webpage but you need to store the state of the last request and check the result of the new request against it.

I hope this was helpful.